# Need help with this Linear Mappings true/false question

Tags: vectors, linear-transformations

Let vector $y$ $\in \mathbb R^3$ with $y\ne0$. If $T:\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ is defined by $T(x)=x+y$ then $T$ is a linear mapping.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Is $T(a + b) = T(a) + T(b)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False, since every linear mapping $T:V\rightarrow U$ have the property $T(0_V)=0_U$. Here $T(\vec{0})=y\neq\vec{0}$

Answer (score 0):

No it is not a linear mapping.  One of the conditions for a map $M$ to be a linear map is that $$M(\alpha x) = \alpha M(x)$$

and $T(x)$ does not respect this condition.